# UI Not updating from ObservableCollection called by a command from a seperate ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, prism

```
private ObservableCollection<ProjectItem> _projectItems;

public ObservableCollection<ProjectItem> DataItems
    {
        get { return _projectItems; }
    }

public ProjectsPanelViewViewModel()
    {
        _projectItems = new ObservableCollection<ProjectItem>();
        _createProjectCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnCreateProjectCommand);
        _saveProjectCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSaveProjectCommand);
    }

private void OnCreateProjectCommand()
    {
        _addProjectViewModel = new AddProjectViewModel();
        AddProjectView view = new AddProjectView();
        view.Show();
    }

    private void OnSaveProjectCommand()
    {
        ProjectItemViewModel _vm = new ProjectItemViewModel();
        _vm.ProjectName = ProjectName;
        _vm.ProjectDescription = ProjectDescription;
        var item = new ProjectItem(_vm);
        _projectItems.Add(item);
    }
```

XAML

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <VM:ProjectsPanelViewViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<StackPanel Name="ProjectsPanel" Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}" >
    <StackPanel Name="ProjectsHeader" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <Label Style="{StaticResource TitleLabelStyleBlue}">projects</Label>
        <Button Name="AddProjects" Margin="10,5,0,0" Style="{StaticResource CircularGreyButtonStyle}" Content="+" ToolTip="Add a new project" Command="{Binding CreateProjectCommand}"/>
        <Button Name="ExpandProjects" Margin="10,5,0,0" Style="{StaticResource CircularGreyButtonStyle}" Content=">" ToolTip="Expand projects"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

When the OnCreateProjectCommand Opens it creates a window with 2 string fields, this then has a button that executes the OnSaveProjectCommand. The commands are executed fine, however the UI does not pick up that the new item has been added to the collection. (When debugging it is in there). If however you change the code from the OnSaveProjectCommand and put it into the OnCreateProjectCommand, and hardcode the simple string values, the UI is updated correctly from the observable collection.

Can anyone give me some guidance as to why this is not working, and also the correct way that I should be spawning up a new window from this command. Should this be done with State Based view navigation from prism? We are already using this for modularisation and commanding.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Try adding Mode=TwoWay to your binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a reference problem there. How do you glue this ViewModels with each other? I'm not familiar with Prism, but it might happen that the VM instance you are viewing on screen is not the same as the one you're debugging. Otherwise it doesn't make sense. Observablecollections usually work just fine, unless you're manipulating them from different threads other than the UI thread. Try using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to spy into the running application to see what your DataContexts are.

Comment: By either Constructor injection or by setting the datacontext in the XAML window. Ive tried to update this with the dispatcher but again it doesnt seem to help.

Comment: Try to spy the running instance of the application with Snoop. It allows you better debugging because you can inspect UI properties as well as data (ViewModels)

Comment: That will be helpful. I think i also need to fire that collection changed event aswell though.

Comment: That is what the problem was, 2 different ViewModels. Snoop told me the VMs were the same, but didnt give me obeject references for these. Actually the only way i could see they were different objects in memory was to attach an object ID to the viewmodels collections in the Visual Studio Debugger. I assume that is an internal IDE cound that checks the object references. Once i seen they were different depending on who the caller was, i could see it was VM ref issue. Fixed within unity by adding new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() to the VM registration.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to HighCores advice, attach an eventhandler to the `CollectionChanged` Event from your ObservableCollection. If the event gets fired you could at least raise the NotifyPropertyChanged for the ObservableCollection manually.

Edit

Example:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CollectionChangedSpike
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ProjectItem> _projectItems = new ObservableCollection<ProjectItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<ProjectItem> ProjectItems
        {
            get { return _projectItems; }
            set { _projectItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("ProjectItems");}
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            //Just for debugging
            ProjectItems.CollectionChanged += OnProjectItemsChanged;
        }

        private void OnProjectItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("ProjectItems");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: OK, what will i need to put in the NotifyPropertChanged event however? As in raise a property change evenr for the Observable Collection?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.